# android service START_STICKY START_NOT_STICKY

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

I need to keep my service always running in background. And starting my service with "startService()" function. I don't want to restart service whatever is Application's state.

Here is my observations.

START_STICKY > if application starts , service is restarting. And service is restarting itself when application closes , too.

START_NOT_STICK > service doesn't work after application closed.

I need a service which always running , and it will receive broadcast when application starts. Services status musn't depend if application is running or not.

Can you help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will want to set a BOOT receiver which starts your Service ALARM (which will wake up intermittently and make sure your Service is running) when the device boots. The ALARM receiver should wakes up every minute (or so) to see that your Service hasn't been cleaned up by Android (which will happen from time to time).

[EDIT]

You'll want a BootReceiver to start your alarm that will look like this:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

          AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                   PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);

          alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 2000,  60000, pendingIntent);
       }
    }
```

And an alarmReceiver would look like this:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";
   // onReceive must be very quick and not block, so it just fires up a Service
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
      Intent i = new Intent(context, MyLovelyService.class);      
      PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,i, 0).send();    
   }
}
```

and lastly this needs to go into your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```

Comment: Thanks Dredel. But my problem is that Service kills itself after application being closed. How can i prevent this ?

Comment: How are you starting the Service? If you have your service started by the ALARM (rather than from your app) then it won't be connected to your Activity in any way... I'll edit my answer to show you an example...

Comment: I am starting my service in applicaton by startservice command. I will try your code. It looks logical. Thank you !

Comment: do i need to use BOOT_COMPLETED. will it give the same effect if i start service after 1 second with alarm manager ? Because it will be hard to test service on device. Need boot everytime

Comment: no no... you can fire that Alarm from anywhere (your activity for instance) in case it wasn't present at boot time

Comment: Hi @Dr.Dredel. I've tried your code. Yes my service is running after BOOT but i launch application and send broadcast to service receiver , i looks like 2 instances of service. Because my function (in service) is being called 2 times. And when i exit application it restarts service again(onStart). I am sure that i am not starting service from my application

Comment: You can't have "2 instances" of the service (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876745/how-to-have-multiple-instance-of-service-in-android) , but if it's already running and you try to launch it again, it will fire the onStart method again (I haven't tested this, but it's easy to figure out).  So... just set some variable that says that your service is already running and then if you find that variable set, just do nothing.

Comment: Thanks. And what do you think about it kills itself and relaunch after application launched ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Do you *want it to kill itself? Or do you want it to live? The ALERT will keep bringing it back to life.