# Bluetooth Into service

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to establish a connection between my phone and bluetooth card within service in android, But i have a problem with service. Service does an auto restart after half an hour. My goal is to keep my service running as long as possible.

```
public void onCreate() {
Log.d("PrinterService", "Service started");   

  super.onCreate();
 }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

 return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
Log.d("PrinterService", "Onstart Command");
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {

    if(bluetoothProvider != null)
        bluetoothProvider = null;

        bluetoothProvider = new BluetoothProvider(getApplicationContext());
        bluetoothProvider.startUpdates();
}

return Service.START_STICKY ;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a sticky service.

You can do this by returning START_STICKY in onStartCommand.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Read also about application:persistent which is "Whether or not the application should remain running at all times". This is more troublesome - System will try not to kill your app which will effect others in the system, you should be careful using it.

refer following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15038770/3110609

Comment: thank you, i did the same thing but Service continues to do an auto restart after half an hour

Comment: U need to use alarm manager.do go through tutorials of alarm manager.

Comment: and i also tried 'android:process="" ' in my manifest, service does an auto restart

Comment: I tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387346/android-service-start-sticky-start-not-sticky

Comment: what do you think about startforeground() ?

Comment: I hav read about startforeground() but sorry i havent tried it so unable to help you in tht case.

Comment: do you think that pb comes from low memory? My Service does not exceed 4Mb

Comment: Sumtimes memory prob might affect services.But as u say ur memory dont exceed 4 mb.i dont think it should affect much.

Comment: maybe phone does this pb? I do not have it on S3. Pb produces on wiko