# How to Access the Instance of the Service from an Activity Other Than the Activity Starting the Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I have a service that is being started in Activity B using:

```
private Intent streamPlayerServiceIntent;
.
.
.
streamPlayerServiceIntent = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), StreamPlayerService.class);
streamPlayerServiceIntent.putExtra("url", result);
getSherlockActivity().startService(streamPlayerServiceIntent);
```

and I would like to access the service instance from Activity A. How can I access the service, which method would be the most suitable way? The service plays a stream from an URL.

I don't want access the service by declaring the intent as static or convert service to be a singleton since I intent to create another instance of the service later.

Comment: How are you going to create another instance of service? at at time only one instance will get all the request.

Comment: Yes, you are right... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876745/how-to-have-multiple-instance-of-service-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is **bind** to the service. It's a little long to explain here (and I would probably end up pasting the manual).

In short, when you bind to the service you provide a callback connection object. This connection object (probably inside your activity) gets notified (similarly to a control's onclickListener) when the binding has been successful and you can retrieve a pointer to the service's instance. Once with a pointer to the service in your hands you can do whatever you want.

Check [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), there's a very good example.